# Show Output of tests written using Jasmine in a specific position on the screen

Tags: html, css, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing tests for my SPA written using angularJS using Jasmine, the outputs for the test show up in the bottom of the html page and get partially hidden because of my page sidebar. What I want to do is show them in a specific position within the screen, I tried putting the test part within a specific div and changing the position of the div, but it does not work. I do not want to show the output of the tests in console, I want them to remain within the main page, but within a specific position of my choice. Any help is appreciated. I can provide the code segment if anyone needs to see. 
Thanks

```
<div style="margin-left:30%;">
                  <script>
                  describe('test', function () {
                      beforeEach(module('myApp'));
                      var $controller;
                      beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
                          $controller = _$controller_;
                      }));
                      describe('deleteEntry', function () {
                          it('Entry should be deleted', function () {
                              var $scope = {};
                              var controller = $controller('movieCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
                              $scope.movies = [
                                  {
                                      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
                                      "rank": "1",
                                      "id": "tt0111161"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "title": "The Godfather",
                                      "rank": "2",
                                      "id": "tt0068646"
                                  }
                              ];
                              $scope.deleteEntry("1");
                              expect($scope.exists("The Shawshank Redemption")).toBe(false);
                              $scope.deleteEntry("2");
                              expect($scope.exists("The Godfather")).toBe(true);
                          });
                      });
                      describe('addEntry', function () {
                          it('Entry should be added', function () {
                              var $scope = {};
                              $scope.movies=[];
                              var controller = $controller('movieCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
                              $scope.addEntry("Testing Movie","1");
                              expect($scope.exists("Testing Movie")).toBe(true);
                              $scope.addEntry("Testing Movie Last","100");
                              expect($scope.exists("Testing Movie Last")).toBe(false);
                          });
                      });
                  });
              </script>
```

Comment: It would be good if you can provide code segment for this. Then it will be easier to help

Comment: I have added the code segment for the test.